# Update a two dimensional variable by row in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Is there any way to update a row from a two dimensional tf.variable with tf.scatter_update. The idea is that the variable is inside a tf.while_loop and in each iteration the selected row is updated with something else. The idea is:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9]]
```

and I want to do something like this

```
a = tf.scatter_update(a, selected_row, updated_row)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code updates one tensor, row by row, from another tensor. Please note that I haven't considered any performance implications.

The key lines are these where I am using a variable( which I think becomes a tensor inside the loop ) and incrementing it.

```
a = tf.scatter_update(a,v,b[i])

v = i + 1
```

Code is this.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def cond(size, i, v):
    return tf.less(i,size)

def body(size, i, v):

    a = tf.get_variable("a",
    [3,3],dtype=tf.int32,initializer=tf.constant_initializer([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]))
    b = tf.get_variable("b",[3,3],dtype=tf.int32,initializer=tf.constant_initializer([[10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18]]))

    a = tf.scatter_update(a,v,b[i])

    v = i + 1

    tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
    with tf.control_dependencies([a]):
        return (size, i+1, v)

with tf.Session() as sess:

    i = tf.constant(0)
    v = tf.Variable(0)
    size = tf.constant(3)
    _,i,v = tf.while_loop(cond,
                    body,
                    [size, i, v])

    a = tf.get_variable("a",[3,3],dtype=tf.int32)

    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    sess.run(init)

    print(sess.run([v,a,i]))
```

Output is

> [3, array([[10, 11, 12],
>          [13, 14, 15],
>          [16, 17, 18]]), 3]

Comment: Ok what if I do not know the tensor b. My problem is that in the loop I call a function and that function returns a tensor t = [x, y, z] and that tensor is the updated tensor which will update the row i.

Comment: Could you add these details to the question ? Do you that 'b' will be new everytime the loop executes ?

Comment: In each iteration there is a new b. The b is like this [x, y, z]. This b represents the updated row from a. So it should be a = tf.scatter_update(a, selected_row, b) somehow.

Comment: What if I do a = a[selected_row, :].assign(b). It works. Is it efficient?

Comment: Is that outside the while loop ? I don't have a good idea about performance considerations.Only good micro benchmarking tools can give you that idea.

Comment: It is inside the loop and it works but I do not how much efficient it is.

Comment: `with tf.control_dependencies` will still be needed. I think. That is a happens-before relationship.

Comment: Yes it is still needed.